# Joining CTE_1 to CTE_2 if CTE_2 has data, if not just give CTE_1 Data

Tags: sql

Is there a way to join CTE_1 to CTE_2 if CTE_2 has data? With this code, it returns nothing if CTE_2 has no data. The common columns are Names and Locations. The issue that I am having is CTE_1 will always have data, but CTE_2 won't get data until around 4-6 hours into the shift.

```
Begin

Create table #Punches
(
    [AEmployeeID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [APERSONFULLNAME] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ACUSTOMER] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ADEPARTMENT] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AEVENTDATE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AINPUNCHDTM1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AOUTPUNCHDTM1] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AINPUNCHDTM2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AOUTPUNCHDTM2] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AINPUNCHDTM3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [AOUTPUNCHDTM3] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ASUPERVISORNAME] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ASUPERVISORID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ASHIFTSTARTTIME] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ASHIFTENDTIME] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ASITE] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ABadge#] [varchar] (255) NULL
)
insert into #Punches
    EXECUTE ('BEGIN FX_RPTSP_MEMPHIS_PUNCHES(); END;') at KR1P1;
end
Begin
Create table #1stScans
(
    ID int identity ,
    [AEmployee Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Dispatch] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [varchar](255) NULL
)
insert into #1stScans
Select * from Openquery(FFLOW,'Execute rudpBenchLocations_today');
end



--Selects Tech Name, Bench Location, 1st Punch, First Scan, and Dwell (COMPLETED and ACCURATE)
BEGIN

WITH CTE_1 AS(
Select
[AEmployee Name] Name1,
Location Location1,
#Punches.AINPUNCHDTM1 as FirstPunch,
Timestamp From
(Select [AEmployee Name],Location,TimeStamp,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION By [AEmployee Name] ORDER BY Timestamp ASC)Dup from #1stScans,#Punches)as FSD

Join #Punches ON [AEmployee Name]=APERSONFULLNAME
where FSD.dup = 1
AND Convert(Date,AINPUNCHDTM1) = Convert(Date,Getdate()))
,CTE_2 AS
(
Select [AEmployee Name] Name2,Location Location2,TimeStamp Timestamp2,AINPUNCHDTM2 LunchPunch,(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION By [AEmployee Name] ORDER BY TimeStamp))as DUP from #1stScans
INNER JOIN #Punches ON [AEmployee Name]=APERSONFULLNAME
AND CONVERT(TIME,Timestamp)>=CONVERT(TIME,AINPUNCHDTM2)
)


***Select 
Name1 as Name,
Location1 as Location,
TimeStamp as [1st TimeStamp],
FirstPunch,
TimeStamp2 as [2nd TimeStamp],
LunchPunch 
FROM CTE_1
Join CTE_2 on Name1 = NAME2
WHERE DUP=1
AND Name2 <> ''***



END

Drop table #Punches
Drop table #1stScans
```

Comment: Your join is vague (ie, defaults to inner)... Use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Tried left join, and still got the same issue

Comment: he's right you need an outer join if you want data from one side to show even if there is no data on the other side.

Comment: OH WOW.... I am such a goof..... Thanks greatly. It was Literally the Where statement that was stopping my left join...  ***Jots that into my little black book*** lol Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a left join, conditions on the right hand table go in the JOIN conditions, not the where clause

```
Select 
       Name1 as Name,
       Location1 as Location,
       TimeStamp as [1st TimeStamp],
       FirstPunch,
       TimeStamp2 as [2nd TimeStamp],
       LunchPunch 
FROM CTE_1
LEFT Join CTE_2 
    on Name1 = NAME2
    AND DUP=1
    AND Name2 <> ''
```

Comment: OH WOW.... I am such a goof..... Thanks greatly. It was Literally the Where statement that was stopping my left join...  ***Jots that into my little black book*** lol Thank you for your help...

Comment: Another question, do you all have advise on how to optimize the procedure? I am currently at 43 seconds. I would "Like" to get it below 25.